# How to redirect perl output in c#

Tags: c#, perl

I'm writing a C# program to interface with a perl script. the script executes rtmpdump and when It gets to actually start to show progress, it gives me an error that the system can not find the file specified.The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo failed. The console and lines variable was not set.

Here is my code that I am using to execute the perl script:

```
ProcessStartInfo prc = new ProcessStartInfo("perl", "script");

                prc.UseShellExecute = false;
                prc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = prc;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine("DONE!");

                sb = new StringBuilder("");

                process.OutputDataReceived +=new DataReceivedEventHandler(linkHandler);

                Console.WriteLine(sb);

private static void linkHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outline)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outline.Data)){
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + outline.Data);
        }
    }
```

and this is the error that I am getting.. : (

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>   Unable to get Terminal Size. The Win32 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo call didn't wo
>   rk. The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work. The resize program
>   didn't work. at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/Term/ReadKey.pm line 373.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Perl script you're trying to run expects to be executed within a terminal, thus failing after attempting to get the terminal's settings...